# Elem_match not chaining "and" in mongoid request

Tags: mongoid, mongodb-query

I have an order with embeded sub_orders.  I'm doing a request to only find sub_orders that have been sent today.  When I use `elem_match` with two clauses it seems to chain inclusively. This seems strange to me as with chaining inside a where clause is exclusive. Is there a way to make `elem_match` criteria exclusive?

```
first_minute = Time.mktime(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day,  0, 0)
last_minute  = Time.mktime(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day,  0, 59)

# Fails sent_at.gte but returns the order anyways
orders = Order.where(:sub_orders.elem_match => {:sent_at.gte => first_minute, :sent_at.lte => last_minute })

# Fails sent_at.gte and returns what I would expect
orders = Order.where(:sub_orders.elem_match => {:sent_at.gte => first_minute})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the aggregate method. For whatever reason, this allows me to query gte and lte when elem_match does not.

```
orders = Order.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind" => "$sub_orders"},
  {"$match" => {
    "sub_orders.sent_at" => {"$gte" => day_ago, "$lte" => now}
  }}
])
```